# How to add my program to the OS X system menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, statusbar

I have created a volume controller for iTunes but I would like this app to place an icon on the OS X system menu bar and have my slider controller drop down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an [`NSStatusItem`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in your app. Have a look at the [Status Bars documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html).

You would normally create a faceless background app by setting the `LSUIElement` key in your Info.plist file to `YES` and have the app create the status item on launch.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After some more searching I found the nickname for those menu items are "menulets", a google search brings up numerous tutorials, in case anyone else has this problem.