# Menu bar to not activate app

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem

I'm trying to work out how my Mac app when running can have it's cute little icon sitting in the dock in the background and then the user can click on the icon in the menu bar and trigger the menu without activating my app into the foreground? Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add my program to the OS X system menu bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687938/how-to-add-my-program-to-the-os-x-system-menu-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow!

I tried to do exactly the same thing a while ago and fount [this](http://cocoatutorial.grapewave.com/2010/01/creating-a-status-bar-application/) tutorial very helpful. It shows just great how to make a status bar application.

I don't know if you want to hide the icon in the dock as well. If you do, take a look at the bottom of the page. You have to set the key `LSUIElement` in the info.plist to 1 (or true).

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: `NSUIElement` and `NSBGOnly` are deprecated in favor of `LSUIElement` and `LSBackgroundOnly`, respectively.

Comment: Thank you. I'll fix it in a minute. I didn't know that.  :-D